# COM1 not accepted in title

Tags: bug, status-completed

A question containing COM1 as title will trigger this error

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1677444/COM1

Server Error in '/' Application.
The resource cannot be found.
Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.

Requested URL: /questions/1677444/COM1

Comment: that of course works for all the other device names as well...

Comment: You should refrain from making short-non explicative titles. This looks like a *feature* to me :)

Comment: agreed, but still a "hole"

Comment: @Stefano Borini: I know, there was a problem some time ago with `web.config` tags too (don't know if it was fixed and I'm way too lazy to look it up, but not lazy enough to stop typing in the comment box provided by our benefactor or overlord, wich one you prefer. I'm sorry I wasted your time when you could be anywhere else doing something productive. Go now. Put that giant **S** down. Please don't hurt me. Stop hitting me. Please! Waaah! ... *pluralization errors censored*)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a known issue of ASP.NET MVC routing, not StackOverflow.

> [ASP.NET MVC Routing vs. Reserved Filenames in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/987105/)

Answer (score 2):

This has been fixed since our upgrade to .Net 4 (though you can't create a title that short anymore anyway...).  [A post by Phil shows the change](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2746438/13249).

Comment: Microsoft has not tested this version on their own site, http://www.microsoft.com/com1.aspx ;-)